# USB Camera for filming insects

Tags: camera, video-camera

I want to do a little study where I need to analyze the behaviour of insects like flies, bees and mosquitos. For this, I want to attach at least one USB camera to my computer, in order to do live analysis operations on the video feed.

I need a camera that is able to capture the insects in indoor settings (distance up to 2 or 3 meters). Can anyone recommend a USB camera with sufficient quality that would be able to do that?

Comment: How much detail do you need? A regular 1080p webcam with the usual wide angle lens at 3m from an insect is barely going to see more than  a black dot blurring past the frame.

Comment: How about the Anker/Eufy "[Indoor Cam 2K](https://www.eufylife.com/products/variant/indoor-cam-2k/T84001W1)" camera? It's marketed as a security camera, but I'll bet it would work great for your needs. They are [regularly discounted to $28 each on Amazon](https://camelcamelcamel.com/product/B08571VZ3Q).

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a Raspberry Pi with a [camera module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module-v2/)?  The camera can do 1080p at 30fps, 720p at 60fps or VGA at 90fps so should hopefully be adequate quality for your application.

You can connect to the Raspberry Pi via Ethernet directly into your PC or connect to it remotely if it is on the same network as your PC. This would be a neat solution if you were to add multiple cameras.

Answer (score 1):

search on amazon for **endoscope**

as cheap as $20, bluetooth to your phone or usb connection

I bought a couple for novelty sake, messing around with like plumbing or inspecting within walls, the field of view is very small but they do work, and for something like insect size if you mount the endoscope so the camera head doesn't move I think it would be ok.  the more expensive ones will have better resolution and capabilities.